# Is it possible to create list of dictionary from list of string data?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

My Input list is of the following type (Note that it includes empty strings):

```
Input = ['NO', 'Part Number', '1', '12334', '2', '45fd33', '']
```

I need to create a list of dictionaries like (Where the empty strings are ignored)

```
[
  {'NO': '1', 'Part Number': '12334'},
  {'NO': '2', 'Part Number': '45fd33'}
]
```

What I have tried so far:

```
dict(enumerate(new_name_list, start=1))
```

and got following output:

```
{1: 'NO', 2: 'Part Number', 3: '1', 4: '12334', 5: '2', 6: '45fd33', 7: ''}
```

How can I get expected output and exclude empty string value from the list?

Comment: Why are you getting the data in this structure instead of a sequence of 2-sequences?

Comment: Right now your expected output is a set of.. well, I'm not sure, it's halfway between a list and a dictionary.  I *think* what you want is a list of dictionaries instead.

Comment: Why your keys are in the same list than your values ? It is possible to have 3, 4 keys instead of 2 ? To have a list of keys separated from the values could be better (unless if if you always have to work with 2 keys).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separate questions that you ask here.

To remove `''` from your list you can pass it through a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> Input = ['NO', 'Part Number', '1', '12334', '2', '45fd33','']
>>> Input_Changed = [i for i in Input if i!='']
>>> Input_Changed
['NO', 'Part Number', '1', '12334', '2', '45fd33']
```

The syntax of your string follows the general rule that the odd elements baring the first two is meant to be `NO` and the even ones are meant to be `Part_Number`.

For this we can use following the `iter` trick:

```
>>> i = iter(Input_Changed[2:])
>>> [{Input_Changed[0]:x,Input_Changed[1]:y} for x,y in zip(i,i)]
[{'Part Number': '12334', 'NO': '1'}, {'Part Number': '45fd33', 'NO': '2'}]
```

The main idea is that `iter` returns an iterator and hence each time you pass an element you consume an element. Thus you get the required output when you [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) (which returns adjacent elements as you are passing the same iterator as both the arguments).

Comment: What's the difference between this "trick" and `zip(Input_Changed[2::2], Input_Changed[3::2])`?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Single iterator using the "trick". When you slice, you are creating two new lists.